Marginal of Exponential Operator in terms of $x$ and $p$
I am effectively looking to compute the marginal,
$\langle x| \exp(\hat x\hat p ) | p \rangle$. Since $[\hat x, \hat p] = i$, it is not simply solved by trivially acting $\hat x$ on to the state on the left and $\hat p$ to the state on the right. Series expanding the exponentially leaves you with a sum over terms involving $(\hat x \hat p)^k$, and the $\hat x$ and $\hat p$'s cannot tractably be commuted through to the left/right. However it feels as though there should be some known identity that gives a nice result for this.
Alternatively, are there any results that allow one to split an exponential of a product of operators?

If I am not mistaken, you can rewrite $XP$  in terms of the ladder operators, which should give that the exponential of $XP$ is proportional to the squeeze operator. Perhaps this can be made useful (e.g. using then the completeness relation of coherent states or so), but I don't know...Anyway, the answer below seems way more straightforward.

That thought occurred to me, though it seemed strange to invoke $a,a^\dagger$ in this problem, which without added context, would not necessarily have anything to do with a harmonic oscillator (though $| p \rangle$ could always be written in the coherent state basis)

There is a standard method.
Recall
$$
\hat x \hat p = -i \int\!\! dx ~|x\rangle x\partial_x \langle x| = 
-i \int\!\! dx ~|x\rangle \partial_{\ln x} \langle x| ~~~\leadsto \\
\exp(\hat x \hat p )= \int\!\! dx ~|x\rangle e^{-i\partial_{\ln x}} \langle x|,
$$
so that
$$
\langle x|\exp(\hat x \hat p )|p\rangle =  e^{-i\partial_{\ln x}}   \langle x|p\rangle =  e^{-i\partial_{\ln x}} e^{ixp}/\sqrt{2\pi}\\ \Large
=  e^{-i\partial_{\ln x}} e^{ie^{\ln x}p}/\sqrt{2\pi} = e^{ie^{\ln x ~ -i}p}/\sqrt{2\pi}=  e^{ie^{-i}xp}/\sqrt{2\pi},
$$
the  penultimate step being the action of the Lagrange shift operator in $\ln x$ by -i.

Very interesting! I guess the $x \partial_x = \partial_{\ln x}$ is another trick I have now :)
